# Textview under ImageView that is resizable in Listview Item layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a listview and in my list item layout I am wanting to put a textview below an imageview.

In my imageview because I am loading bitmaps into it I have had to set it up so that the images will resize to their correct size when they are loaded into the imageview. I have done this by setting the imageview's layout height and width parameters to fill parent. Because of this when I put the textview below the imageview, the textview does not appear...

I have tried placing another linearlayout around the imageview and fixing the height so that it will resize to a max height but the textview still does not appear...

Here is my layout file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/race_entrant"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:paddingTop="2dip"
android:paddingBottom="2dip"
android:paddingRight="2dip"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
android:cacheColorHint="#E0EAF1">
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="50dip"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/linearLeft"
    android:paddingLeft="2dip"
    android:paddingRight="2dip"
    android:paddingTop="2dip"
    android:paddingBottom="2dip"
    android:background="#E0EAF1"
    android:cacheColorHint="#E0EAF1">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtEntrantNo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/entrant_number"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:cacheColorHint="#E0EAF1" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="41dip">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgJockey"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:cacheColorHint="#E0EAF1" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtForm"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        style="@style/entrant_form" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The textview that I am referring to has the id txtForm.

How can I do this so that the textview is visible along with the imageview?

Comment: check this link: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

Comment: Would you mind post some mockup design picture of your list item, I try your code and found that all of element sit at the left. Do you expect to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the ImageView a layout_weight.  I put an image and some text in just for reference.  Here is how it should look:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/race_entrant"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:cacheColorHint="#E0EAF1"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingBottom="2dip"
android:paddingRight="2dip"
android:paddingTop="2dip" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLeft"
    android:layout_width="50dip"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#E0EAF1"
    android:cacheColorHint="#E0EAF1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="2dip"
    android:paddingLeft="2dip"
    android:paddingRight="2dip"
    android:paddingTop="2dip" >

    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/imgJockey"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:cacheColorHint="#E0EAF1" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Text"
        android:id="@+id/txtEntrantNo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/entrant_number"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:cacheColorHint="#E0EAF1" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear with my question... and the layout I posted was missing the textview. I have now updated it. The textview is the view which is not appearing... I have tried setting the layout_weight="1" on the textview and on the imageview and it does work. However now the textview at the bottom is cut off... So it looks like it is not resizing the layout properly.

Comment: Not sure if your comment is still current or not since the question has been marked as "accepted".  However, at this point it is probably easier to ask what you are trying to accomplish.  If it is just text over an image over text, I think they are easier ways.  Also, incidentally, the layout you posted above is not hiding any views.  I did remove the styles, though.  Maybe that is the core of your issue, if you are still having one.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use **Relative Layout** in Place of Linear Layout and add Text View And Image View Inside that.